# How to compare the efficiency between two functions?

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

One of them is `n*sqrt(n)` and another one is `n*log(n)*log(n)`. Is there any   method to compute which one is more efficient?

Comment: Simplify: compare `sqrt(n)` to `log(n)*log(n)`

Comment: Do you want to compare the time complexity of `sqrt` vs `log`?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `n*sqrt(n)` and `n*log(n)*log(n)` are the complexity (Big O) of your two functions, you need to compare the two expressions.

To compare two simple expressions (aka functions) in a fast an easy way, you could use googles search.

Just enter

```
y = x*log(x)*log(x), y = x*sqrt(x)
```

in the search field and it will draw the two graphs and you can compare them.

Alternatively you can subtract the functions like:

```
y = x*log(x)*log(x) - x*sqrt(x)
```

Then you have a single graph and you can easily check when the result is greater/less than zero.

Answer (score 2):

Plot graph for various values of `n` starting from `0,1,...` and observe which function grows higher. **The one with less growth is more efficient.**

I am attaching the picture of graphs for both function :

[image]

Left one is `n*log(n)*log(n)` and right one is `n*sqrt(n)`. You see that, `n*log(n)*log(n)` is growing less higher. So it's efficient :)

Comment: You ought to mention the online website used for creating the graphs. :)

Comment: Is it a must to mention that name?? Anyways, i used `fooplot`.

Answer (score 0):

The Big-O-Notation is meant to give you a quick impression, *without* calculating a lot. So creating a graph might be overkill for many cases.

The usual suspects in the Big-O notation are:

- O(1)
- O(log n)
- O(n)
- O(n²)
- O(n<sup>c</sup>)

Where `O(1)` is fastest and each is slower than the one before. There exist [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions), of course, but those 5 you'll see all the time.

In your example. One only has to know that

- `O(n²) = O(n) * O(n)`
- `O(log n)` is faster than `O(n)`

thus follows:

`O(log n) * O(log n)` is faster than `O(n) * O(n)`

(because fast * fast is faster than slow * slow)

thus follows:

`x * O(log n) * O(log n)` is faster than `x * O(n) * O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

> One of them is `n*sqrt(n)` and another one is `n*log(n)*log(n)`. ... which one is more efficient?

Simplify

```
n*sqrt(n) versus  n*log(n)*log(n)
compares the same as 
sqrt(n) versus  log(n)*log(n)
compares the same as 
n versus  power(log(n),4)
```

Note growth and the ratio `f(n)/g(n)` of the two

```
  n        power(log(n),4)  ratio
      1          0             - 
     10          1             10
    100         16             12.3...
   1000         81             39.0...
  10000        256            160.0
 100000        625            771.6...
1000000       1296           4164.9...
```

If ratio tends to infinity, `n*log(n)*log(n)` is more efficient.
If ratio tends to 0, `n*sqrt(n)` is more efficient.
If ratio tends to a positive constant, there are equivalent efficiency.

Conclusion: `n*log(n)*log(n)` is more efficient.

Note: it makes no difference if analysis uses `log10(n)`, `log2(n)`, `log(n)`,

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed empirically by executing a plain program, like the following in Java:

```
public class AlgoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int n = 1024;

        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;

        int b = 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Math.sqrt(n); j++) {
                sum1 ++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("n*sqrt(n) = " + sum1);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j*=b) {
                for (int k = 1; k <= n; k*=b) {
                    sum2 ++;
                }   
            }
        }
        System.out.println("n*log(n)*log(n) = " + sum2);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sub; j ++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < sub; k ++) {
                    sum3 ++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("[Sophisticated] n*log(n)*log(n) = " + sum3);
    }
}
```

Where sum1 is the number of iterations performed by a program whose complexity is n*sqrt(n), and the next one's complexity is n*log(n)*log(n).

And I chose base 2 because there's a slight relation between log base and square root function.